# add the user name to menu when user is logged in

Tags: menus, login, logout, username

i have this code but its not working it throws syntax error, unexpected '}' error

```
function my_custom_menu_item($items, $args)
{
    if(is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary')
    {
        $user=wp_get_current_user();
        $name=$user->display_name; // or user_login , user_firstname, user_lastname
        $items .= '<li><a href="">Welcome '.$name.'</a></li>';
        $items.= //Change Password, Logout, etc
    }
    elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('wp-login.php') .'">Log In</a></li>';
        $items.= //Sign up, Lost Password
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_custom_menu_item');
```

Comment: read this for the syntax error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them

Comment: Unexpected } probably means you forgot a ;

Answer (score 1):

You have an errors in

```
$items.= //Change Password, Logout, etc
```

and

```
$items.= //Sign up, Lost Password
```

you haven`t value for assign.Set something into $items variable or delete this strings and all will work.

Comment: Thank u for reply yes errors were solved but i didnt get a result

Comment: i want to display username in primary menu

Comment: look here `add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_custom_menu_item' );`. You use 2 parameters in your function and you need add fourth argument in `add_filter();`.

Change your hook call to `add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_custom_menu_item');`

Comment: i cant understand can u give more information for this problem

Comment: See [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/#Hook_to_WordPress) If you accept more than 1 parametr in your function ($items, $args for your situation), you should set `accepted_args` to parameters count.
for you just replace your `add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_custom_menu_item' );` to `add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_custom_menu_item', 10, 2);` and all will work